# Getting input from a file & storing average in it

Tags: c++

So it surely happens when you revise "file handling" after a long time. Well I am a bit stuck in this code and I've used debugging. I am taking integers from a file: rows columns and then I have to store their average in the very same file.

PS: It works if I use another file to store average.

```
void main()
{

fstream f("abc.txt", ios::out | ios::app | ios::in);

int rows, cols;

f >> rows;
f >> cols;
int sum = 0, inp;
int *avg = new int[rows];

for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    sum = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        f >> inp;
        sum += inp;
    }
    avg[i] = (sum / cols);
}

f << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    f << avg[i];
}

f.close();
delete [] avg;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have to store it in the same file? Process the data, add the averages and write the data to a new temp file. Delete the old file and rename the new one the same as the original. Essentially you have added the averages to the "same" file.

Comment: Is the problem that when you try to write back to the file it doesn't take it? Like the values are not there when you open it. What actually is the problems?

Comment: @Jay Yeah the values are not there when I open the file.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the file I/O, your code has two (rather small) problems:

- When you write the values, you don't truncate the file.  I don't know whether you want this.
- Your output is not delimited by any spaces or newlines which makes it rather unreadable.

The second point is fixed rather trivially.

For the first, you could close the file and then re-open it for writing.  If you do so, then you should only open it for reading the first time.  That said, it appears rather strange to me that a program overwrites the data it has just processed.  This sounds like a dangerous and generally not very useful application.  What are your reasons for not writing the data to another file?

**Update:** I have created the following `abc.txt` file:

```
5 3
11 12 13
21 22 23
31 32 33
41 42 43
51 52 53
```

After running your program as it stands, the contents of the file are changed to :

```
5 3
11 12 13
21 22 23
31 32 33
41 42 43
51 52 53

1222324252
```

If this isn't what you want and my above guess what you might want instead is wrong too, please explain what you want instead.

Comment: Its a small task given to us and I have to do it that way. 
Well the int values will be in the next lines in the file accordingly and I just have to take their average, store it in the avg[] array and then store them in the very same file in the next two lines.

Comment: Well there is no option to post a photograph here otherwise I may show you the abc.txt file.

Comment: Assuming that `abc.txt` is a text file, a photograph might not be the most appropriate media for sharing.